# How to show history data on a day basis while data in table is on seconds basis?

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have a table with timestamp precision up to seconds (table A) and the business requirement is to show history data on a day, week, month and even year basis. Database = Oracle and backend application is Java spring boot.

Table:

```
╔════╤══════╤═════════════════════╗
║ id │ data │ created             ║
╠════╪══════╪═════════════════════╣
║ 1  │ 40   │ 2017-10-06 10:00:00 ║
╟────┼──────┼─────────────────────╢
║ 2  │ 30   │ 2017-10-06 23:59:59 ║
╟────┼──────┼─────────────────────╢
║ 3  │ 1000 │ 2017-10-07 12:00:00 ║
╚════╧══════╧═════════════════════╝
```

Sample expected output:

```
╔══════╤════════════╗
║ data │ created    ║
╠══════╪════════════╣
║ 70   │ 2017-10-06 ║
╟──────┼────────────╢
║ 1000 │ 2017-10-07 ║
╚══════╧════════════╝
```

I can see two options here:

1. create some other table (table B) or store procedure to automatically accumulate data on days by doing sum on the table A and only query table B/store procedure.
2. let backend application query data from the table A directly with correct SQL.

Can anybody please suggest if there is more options and which is best?

Comment: *query data from the table A directly with correct SQL.*  why would you want to use correct sql?

Comment: if not correct sql then what? wrong sql?

Comment: I was being sarcastic - of course use correct sql, incorrect sql will not work

Comment: done and updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple `group by`. To get rid of the time part of the timestamp, you can either use `trunc()` or `to_char()`:

```
select sum(data) as data,
       trunc(created) as day_created
from the_table
group by trunc(created);
```

or

```
select sum(data) as data,
       to_char(created, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as day_created
from the_table
group by to_char(created, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

`to_char()` is more flexible when dealing with other levels of aggregation, e.g. to get the numbers per month:

```
select sum(data) as data,
       to_char(created, 'yyyy-mm') as month_created
from the_table
group by to_char(created, 'yyyy-mm');
```